# How can I iterate over two lists without using zip?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I want to use randint function in zip. Please find my code below and suggest:

```
import random

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
rr = random.randint(1,100)
hh = zip(list1, rr)
for x,v in hh:
    print(x,v)
```

Desired Output:
I want `x` will show from `list1` but `v` show random numbers

Comment: `for x in list1: print(x, random.randint(1,100))`?

Comment: In  your code, `rr = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(len(list1))]`

Comment: You don't have two lists (`rr` is an integer). Anyway, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for `zip()` shows what it is equivalent to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `zip`, you need to generate an iterable (e.g. a list) of random integers. In your special case, this can be achieved with `rr = [random.randint(1,100) for i in list1]`. The square brackets `[...]`initialize a list of `random.randint(1,100)` for every item `i` in `list1`.

Using this snippet:

```py
import random

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
rr = [random.randint(1,100) for i in list1]
hh = zip(list1, rr)
for x,v in hh:
    print(x,v)
```

will give you the following output:

```
a 36
b 36
c 79
d 58
```